# Region transformation under a mapping

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, transformation

I have the transformation
$$
f(x, y) = (x^2-y^2, 2 x y)
$$
and the region $A = \{(x, y): x>0 \}$. I need to find the image of $A$ under $f$,i.e., $B=f(A)$.

I think A is invariant under the transformation, but using ParametricPlot in Mathematica shows otherwise. Is there a systematic way to arrive at the correct region $B$?

[image: Transformed region plot from MATHEMATICA]

[image]

Comment: Hint: what is the image of $(r\cos{\theta},r\sin{\theta})$?

Comment: It is $(r^2 \cos {2 \theta}, r^2 \sin{2 \theta})$. What then?

Comment: Good. So what point are of the form $(r^2\cos{2\theta},r^2\sin{2\theta})$ where $r\cos{\theta} > 0$?

Comment: I understand your gist, but this ParametricPlot from MATHEMATICA is confusing me.

Comment: It’s wrong. Either you didn’t use it well or it has a bug, because the image of $A$ should (obviously) be unbounded. Note also that the shape you’re seeing is dubious because the scales are different on both sides.

Comment: Suppose I take the image of the line $x=1/2$ under the transformation. Would not the x-coordinate of the transformation $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2 x y)$, given by $x^2-y^2$, be negative for sufficiently large $y$?

Comment: Yes, it certainly would.

Comment: That would make the answer below incorrect. So what is the correct the answer? is $f(A)$ the entire plane $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: What do you get when mapping $(r,\theta) \in \mathbb{R}^+ \times (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ to $(r^2,2\theta)$? If the (formal) answer isn’t clear, draw a picture (without Mathematica, of course). Draw random points in $A$ and try to place their images on the plane.

Comment: I did do it randomly, by hand and by Mathematica (there should not be a bug in such a basic function as randomly selecting points and transforming them), max value of r that I took was 10. I am getting  a disk of radius 100. So I think if I take r to infinity, I would cover the whole plane? correct? (see the added plot in the original post).

Comment: Almost, but not quite. There *are* some points that you won’t be able to reach, from $A$. Can you see (or deduce) which ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a function from $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$, so let's apply the substitution for polar coordinates $\begin{cases}x=\rho\cos\theta\\y=\rho\sin\theta \end{cases}$.
The set $A=\mathbb R^+\times\mathbb R$ is defined in the complex plane taking $\rho\in(0,+\infty),\theta \in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and the image of the set $A$ is given by $f\Big(\{z\in\mathbb C:\rho\in(0,+\infty),\theta \in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\}\Big)=\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x<0,y=0\}$.
Observe that (in order to have an idea of what's happening "near" the $y$ axis)
$$\sqrt{\varepsilon^2+1}(\cos(3\pi/2+\alpha_{\varepsilon})+i\sin(3\pi/2+\alpha_{\varepsilon}))\overset{f}\mapsto (\varepsilon^2+1)(\cos(\pi+\bar\alpha_{\varepsilon})+i\sin(\pi+\bar\alpha_{\varepsilon}))$$

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I computed, i.e., the right half-plane. Which means that A is invariant under the transformation (excluding the boundary maybe). But MATHEMATICA is giving me this weird plot which is confusing me. Is it incorrect?

Comment: If we take a point in $\mathbb S^1\cap \mathbb R^+$, for example $P=(1/2,1/2)$, its images will have distance $1/2$ from the origin, while the point $P$ has distance $\sqrt 2 /2>1/2$ from the origin. So I think the program shows you how the map transforms $\overline{\mathbb B_1(0,0)}$. I think that the picture you added is incorrect because in our case we don't consider the y axis...

Comment: Suppose I take the image of the line $x=1/2$ under the transformation. Would not the x-coordinate of the transformation $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2 x y)$, given by $x^2-y^2$, be negative for sufficiently large $y$?

Comment: Points on the line $r: x=1/2$ would be of the form $(1/2,\bar y)$ so for a generic $P\in r$, we have $f((1/2,\bar y))=(1/4-\bar y^2,\bar y)$. Can you see where the points of the line are now? (It's better in my opinion defining $f$ as a map $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$)

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to write $\mathbb R^2\setminus \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x<0,y=0\}$